# extract column of numbers and sort

Tags: java

I want to create a Java program that has the following text file as input:

```
Calculating KNN parameter
Parameter: 1 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535227753624112

Parameter: 2 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 3.7245670622636187

Parameter: 3 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 3.9362841303832017

Parameter: 4 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.843214570109396

Parameter: 5 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.272961320042017

Parameter: 6 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.470106704332144

Parameter: 7 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.882240503856739

Parameter: 8 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 6.292034572575386

Parameter: 9 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 6.768597736578583

Parameter: 10 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 7.363156542812285

Parameter: 11 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 7.94830050269379

Parameter: 12 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 8.66008903038875

Parameter: 13 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 9.114407610375434

Parameter: 14 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 9.613416435385924

Parameter: 15 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 9.996985154183648
Done!
Calculating WKNN parameter
Parameter: 1 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195745

Parameter: 2 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.828108501703112

Parameter: 3 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 3.103403533760642

Parameter: 4 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 3.6864500170894723

Parameter: 5 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.040592423213244

Parameter: 6 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.184767230931307

Parameter: 7 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.473391782511176

Parameter: 8 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.682784733026703

Parameter: 9 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 4.959394725752682

Parameter: 10 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.256765042378009

Parameter: 11 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.5007236666369534

Parameter: 12 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 5.844052147012272

Parameter: 13 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 6.120608429925178

Parameter: 14 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 6.385641690580632

Parameter: 15 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 6.62154087396507
Done!
Calculating MAP parameter
Parameter: 1 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.1619860115120555

Parameter: 2 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 3 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 4 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 5 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 6 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 7 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 8 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 9 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743

Parameter: 10 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7535225490195743
Done!
Calculating MMSE parameter
Parameter: 1 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: NaN

Parameter: 2 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7498889149108856

Parameter: 3 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.7806398141014868

Parameter: 4 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.8209795860443478

Parameter: 5 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.8764885946976129

Parameter: 6 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 1.9505246960583114

Parameter: 7 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.041719152989117

Parameter: 8 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.1448642832455125

Parameter: 9 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.253804843291688

Parameter: 10 Positions: 290 Avg. Error: 2.365860366623
Done!
```

And I want tho extract the numbers after avg. error then sort them and finally write them to other text file as output, for example for the previous sample this is the desired output:

```
1.749888915
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522549
1.753522775
1.780639814
1.820979586
1.876488595
1.950524696
2.041719153
2.144864283
2.161986012
2.253804843
2.365860367
2.828108502
3.103403534
3.686450017
3.724567062
3.93628413
4.040592423
4.184767231
4.473391783
4.682784733
4.84321457
4.959394726
5.256765042
5.27296132
5.470106704
5.500723667
5.844052147
5.882240504
6.12060843
6.292034573
6.385641691
6.621540874
6.768597737
7.363156543
7.948300503
8.66008903
9.11440761
9.613416435
9.996985154
```

any recommendations on how to achieve this?

this is the code to read the files:

```
public class extract2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    File inputFile = new File("offline1.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("offline_out.txt");
    File inputFile1 = new File("testing.txt");
    File tempFile1 = new File("testing_out.txt");
}
```

How I want to do it:
 read the file line by line and extract the numbers after ": " and sabe it into an arraylist, then sort the elements in the array list, finally write the results of the array list

Comment: Yes, write some code.

Comment: Cut short your input and output while sharing here.  It doesn't make a difference to the original question.  .To your question,  read from the file use string functions.  See java docs for string.  And then when u r stuck people here could instantly help you out.  I m sure otherwise too you will get help. But try this

Comment: Atleast post ur logic or algorithm

Comment: Remove `throws java.lang.Exception` and use `try-catch` blocks properly. Read on Java IO and String. You will learn that `File` does not read anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<Double> set = new TreeSet();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if(line.contains("Error) {
      set.add(Double.valueOf(line.split("Error: ")[1]));
     }
}
```

In set you have ordered error values, just print them in a loop.

Comment: Appreciate you are trying to help.  But Is it good to share the code in this scenario? I felt no.   Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? That he should learn the basics and i'm taking chance for it from him? Maybe but it's not ready piece of code and probably he has to modify it somehow so he will eventually learn. If you guys think i shoulnd post that code just downvote me to let me know that

Comment: yes, and I do not know if I am correct thinking that way, hence didn't downvote